# How to convert coordinate from kinect 2.0 camera space to kinect color space manually?

Tags: 3d, kinect, kinect-sdk, coordinate-systems

How to convert coordinate from kinect 2.0 camera space to kinect color space manually?
If I use ICoordinateMapper::MapCameraPointToColorSpace() all ok.

But I need to make it by hand. I try this code:

XMMATRIX mProj = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( float(43.*MATH_PI/180.), 1920.f/1080.f, 1, 1000. );
XMVECTOR ColorSpace = XMVector3Transform(v, mProj);

float x = 0.5f * ( XMVectorGetX(ColorSpace) + 1) * 1920.f;

float y = 0.5f * (-XMVectorGetY(ColorSpace) + 1) * 1080.f;

x and y differ from result MapCameraPointToColorSpace()

update:
If the projected coordinate 0,0,1 and 0,0,4 coordinate, we get a different value of x. Moreover, it would not coincide with the center of the screen.
The only explanation that occurred to me - is that the center coordinates CameraSpace, does not coincide with ColorCamera. It may coincide with DepthCamera. I added to x 3 centimeters to the original coordinates, shifting toward the center of the infrared camera. The result was better, but still there is no exact match.

What is the distance between the cameras kinekt 2.0?

Comment: 1. Why do you want do this? What's wrong with using the coordinate mapper? 2. The CameraSpace of the Kinect SDK does indeed refer to the IR-camera. See [the documentation](here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785530.aspx#ID4EDB).

Comment: I need fit Kinect data,my 3d scene (perspective render) and color frame from color Kinect camera. Best way: convert Kinect data on vertex shader. Really I can use coordinate mapper instead but coordinate mapper did not give me Z value, it give only x,y. I made VFOV and HFOV same as in Kinect color camera in my 3D render but I feel that color camera point shifted and rotated from Camera space coordinate center. So I am Ask: what exactly formula use koordinate mapper?

Comment: When you use the coordinate mapper to map to *camera space*, it does give X, Y, *and Z*. But watch out, those values are in meters, not millimeters.